# Different query results for local server and production server

Tags: python, django, postgresql

**Without changing the code and updating**, the display order of pictures on my production server(django,postgresql,bootstrap,nginx,uwsgi) has changed(see the picture).

[Before/now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZ9Mo.jpg)

I can't reproduce this problem on my local server with same backup/code...

In Django ORM I have this result:

1. local:

```
Car.objects.filter(model=1)
<QuerySet [<CarImage: 1>, <CarImage: 2>, <CarImage: 3>]>
```

2. production:

```
Car.objects.filter(model=1)
<QuerySet [<CarImage: 3>, <CarImage: 2>, <CarImage: 1>]>
```

Reboot nginx/postgresql didn't help.
What could have happened and how to fix it?

Comment: The order of query results is arbitrary if no `ORDER BY` clause is defined.  If you want the rows in a particular order you must specify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ordering is done at DB level so if you are not using the same DB engine the results might differ, to fix the issue just do that :

```
Car.objects.filter(model=1).order_by("pk")
```

or

```
Car.objects.filter(model=1).order_by("-pk")
```

From the documentation :

> if a query doesn’t have an ordering specified, results are returned
> from the database **in an unspecified order**. A particular

Comment: I use same DB version/backup. Could DB change the ordering without my intervention?

Comment: Yes, that is why you need to specify on your code which ordering so you are sure of the output like I show you.

Comment: @plurim see my answer, I have added an explanation from the documentation

Comment: @plurim: Without an order, there is no order. You have to tell the database how to order, if you want an order. Why is the order 1-2-3 the correct order and 3-2-1 is not the correct one, if you don't tell me (or the database in this case) what the correct order is.